# How do I match vowels?

Tags: python, loops

I am having trouble with a small component of a bigger program I am in the works on. Basically I need to have a user input a word and I need to print the index of the first vowel.

```
word= raw_input("Enter word: ")
vowel= "aeiouAEIOU"

for index in word:
    if index == vowel:
        print index
```

However, this isn't working. What's wrong?

Comment: Please try to give your questions more descriptive titles in the future.

Comment: a small hint: in the loop you're comparing the whole content of 'vowel' with each of the letters of the given word

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
word = raw_input("Enter word: ")
vowels = "aeiouAEIOU"

for index,c in enumerate(word):
    if c in vowels:
        print index
        break
```

`for .. in` will iterate over actual characters in a string, not indexes. `enumerate` will return indexes as well as characters and make referring to both easier.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder about being able to search inside strings with the 'for ... in' keywords!

Answer (score 4):

Just to be different:

```
import re

def findVowel(s):
    match = re.match('([^aeiou]*)', s, flags=re.I)
    if match:
        index = len(match.group(1))
        if index < len(s):
            return index
    return -1  # not found
```

Comment: Won't work, `re.match()` only matches at the beginning of the string. You have to use `re.search()` instead. And you're looking for letters that are *not* vowels.

Comment: Um, actually it works correctly (although I agree it's not the most elegant); starting at the beginning of the string, I get as many non-vowels as possible. If the result is the same length as the original string, there are no vowels, so return -1 (same usage-pattern as str.find()); otherwise return the match-length (= the index of the first vowel).

Comment: @Chinmay: if you're going to downvote me, it would be *nice* if it were for an actually correct reason; failing that, it would be nice not to be downvoted at all. Just, like, a subtle hint.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quite grok what you were doing the first time around. Now it won't let me take back my vote :(

Comment: PS: I really should learn to not vote on answers (up or down) when I'm tired. If you make an inconsequential edit, I can remove the downvote.

Answer (score 2):

The same idea using [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
word = raw_input("Enter word: ")
res = [i for i,ch in enumerate(word) if ch.lower() in "aeiou"]
print(res[0] if res else None)
```

Answer (score 1):

index == vowel asks if the letter index is equal to the entire vowel list. What you want to know is if it is contained in the vowel list. See some of the other answers for how in works.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative solution, and arguably a more elegant one, is to use the `re` library.

```
import re
word = raw_input('Enter a word:')
try: 
    print re.search('[aeiou]', word, re.I).start()
except AttributeError:
    print 'No vowels found in word'
```

In essence, the `re` library implements a regular expression matching engine. `re.search()` searches for the regular expression specified by the first string in the second one and returns the first match. `[aeiou]` means "match a or e or i or o or u" and `re.I` tells `re.search()` to make the search case-insensitive.

Comment: Better - I was not aware of the SRE_Match.start() method. Live and learn ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(len(word)):
  if word[i] in vowel:
    print i
    break
```

will do what you want.

"for index in word" loops over the characters of *word* rather than the indices. (You can loop over the indices and characters together using the "enumerate" function; I'll let you look that up for yourself.)

Comment: -1. Don't encourage bad practices. `enumerate` is the Pythonic thing to do here.

Comment: My intention wasn't to encourage bad practices, but to present something as digestible as possible for someone who's plainly a beginner, while giving a pointer to the more-Pythonic thing to be looked up at leisure. Oh well.